# How can I disable Mac OS Lion asking if I really want to open a downloaded file?

Tags: security, mac, macos

I already tried this:

```
cd ~/Downloads
find . -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine
```

But it doesn't seem to work under Mac OS X 10.7 (aka. Lion) anymore:

```
xattr: ./cabin/Cabin-Bold.otf: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine
```

Comment: I think this is more for SuperUser...

Comment: display all extended attributes via xattr and see whether some new attribute is set on the file

Comment: Unix type commands to configure one's Operating System... not really a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this under Lion but

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

**and then restarting** should totally disable this functionality.

Comment: question : where should i put this setting?