# How do I disable quarantine on Lion?

Tags: macos, finder, security, uti

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get rid of the quarantine "Do you want to open this?" warning because I don't like it.

The well documented way (defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO) does NOT work.

Also, I've used the [Secrets Preference pane](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) and that doesn't work either. As soon as I uncheck the box and close the pane and reopen, it's still checked.

(I've tried rebooting right after these methods, no dice.)

Comment: `LSQuarantine -bool false` does work for me. And it was accepted as an answer to: [How can I disable Mac OS Lion asking if I really want to open a downloaded file?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/how-can-i-disable-mac-os-lion-asking-if-i-really-want-to-open-a-downloaded-file)

Answer (score 2):

Never tried to disable the behavior entirely, but you can always remove the quarantine from a file with xattr. For example:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine ./*
```

I think of it less as a moron check than it is a safeguard from browser vulnerabilities that might otherwise download and something without your knowledge.

Comment: To do this systematically, you could have Safari download to an obscure/alternate folder and set up folder actions using Automator to systematically strip the quarantine from all files and then move the file back into downloads at the end of the folder action.

Comment: Why even bother with an alternate folder--can't you just set the folder action up on Downloads? You'd have to adjust the script a tad to only work on the file in question, but I think it'd be possible.

Comment: I think you have to get the file out of the action folder or else it loops continually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Automator folder action that will remove the quarantine flag from files as they are downloaded to the Downloads folder:

1. Make a new Folder Action workflow in Automator
2. In the "Choose folder" menu, choose your Downloads folder
3. Add a "Run Shell Script" command
4. Change the "Pass input" menu to "as arguments"
5. Change the script to:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "$f"
done
```

Finally, save the workflow with whatever name you want and it should start working immediately.